# Background image issues in a HTML5 emitted by MVC4 application

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on an mvc4 application and i was trying to put a background image url for an element laying on a masterpage file '`_Layout.cshtml`' but failed, i am not able to see the background  image at all .My image is located in

> Images-> master -> test.bmp

I put it like a backgroundimage as shown below

```
<body>
 <header style="background-image:url(../Images/master/test.bmp);position: relative; top: -20px;width:100% ">
</header>
</bpdy>
```

Can any body suggest me what went wrong here?

Is there any syntax issue? or background image will not be working in Mvc4 html5 at all

**Update**

I created an Html page and copied this contents and their in design view i can see the image.Now i really wonder what is going wrong over there

**UPDATE**

I set height and now it is coming ,but issue is it is not coming in IIS,when i run in visual studio development server it is working fine.What will be the reason any guess?

Comment: Does background-image:url(/Images/master/IWHeader-v2-Mid.bmp) work?

Comment: try removing position: and top:

Comment: @ buffjape in order to remove the blank space on top of the body, i did it like that .IF i remove blank space will come on top of the website

Comment: No luck at all in either way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution `@Url.Content(~path to image)` will fix all kinds of issues